# Returning an Array of Largest Number in sub-arrays of an Array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the largest number of each sub-array in the array
I sorted them but I can't seem to get my result.
The result should be an array of the largest number of each sub-array.

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i+=1){
    for(var n = 0; n < arr[i].length; n+=1 ){
      arr[n].sort(function(a, b){return b-a});
    }
      console.log(arr[i][0]);
  }
  return arr[i][0];
}

largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this. You do not need the second loop, also create a temp array and put the values there.

```js
function largestOfFour(arr) {
var tmparr = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i+=1){
    //for(var n = 0; n < arr[i].length; n+=1 ){
      arr[i].sort(function(a, b){return b-a});
   // }
      tmparr.push(arr[i][0]);
  }
  console.log(tmparr)
  return tmparr;
}

largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You only have to loop through the array once and create a temporary array to store the largest numbers. Using `Math.max()` allows you to get the largest number within each array. There's no need to sort the arrays when `Math.max()` will already find the largest number for us.

```js
function largestOfFour(arr) {
    let largestNumbers = []
    arr.forEach(innerArr => {
        let largestNumberOfInnerArray = (Math.max(...innerArr))
        largestNumbers.push(largestNumberOfInnerArray)
    });
    return largestNumbers
  }
   console.log(largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]));
```

Comment: Thanks alot. This worked, but after i added var, like this:
    var largestNumbers = [];

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I've updated the post

Answer (score 1):

```js
function largestInArrays(... arrays) {
  return arrays.map(a => Math.max(...a));
}

console.log(largestInArrays([4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]));
```

This works because `Math.max` combined with the `...` argument trick will return the largest numerical value within an array and `.map` allows you to create a new array from the old array by performing an operation on each element of the array.

Comment: While I added an upvote to this answer, you don't really need the ellipsis (...) in the function definition, you only need it in the return line. This answer is simple and efficient.

Comment: @SundayIkpe The reason the ellipsis are in the function definition is because I want all of the arguments to be treated as a single array (so the outer brackets aren't necessary when calling the function). Hence the name change from `largestOfFour` to `largestInArrays`. However looking back at the original question it seems I might have mistaken the specific wanted functionality here.

Answer (score 1):

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  const largestNumb = [];
  // loop through the array
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i+=1){
  // loop through each sub-array (of grabbed array), and sort the numbers in descending order.
      arr[i].sort(function(a, b){return b-a});
      console.log(arr[i][0]);
  // save each of the first value (largest num) in an array
      largestNumb.push(arr[i][0]);
  }
  // console.log(largestNumb);
  return largestNumb;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use underscore.js to achieve this:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.12.0/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script>
    function largestOfFour(arr){
      return arr.map(a => _.max(a));
    }
</script>
```

Tryining

```
largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
```

your result will be:

```
 [5, 27, 39, 1001]
```

Comment: Regular sort does a string comparison not a numerical comparison

Comment: Yea, I have updated with underscoreJS. That way it behaves the way you want. Its the simplest answer I could think of.

Answer (score 0):

Functions in javascript have variables sometimes. A variable saves a value to use whenever coders want. But functions have specific scopes so variables can be defined twice in a function. For example

```js
let food = 'banana';
console.log(food) // it shows 'banana'
function digestion() {
let food = 'poop'
console.log(food) // it shows 'poop'
}
console.log(food) // it still shows 'banana'
```

So scopes can define values differently. But in `largestOfFour` function `arr[i][0]` seems out of `for` loof. Seems there is a little mistake. Without the line the function works.

```js
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i+=1){
    for(var n = 0; n < arr[i].length; n+=1 ){
      arr[n].sort(function(a, b){return b-a});
    }
      console.log(arr[i][0]);
  }
  //return arr[i][0];
}

largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
```